# Close anywhere sldenav overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to close the menu where you clicked anywhere on the screen
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a click event listener to the window and call your closeNav function.

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === 'HTML') {
        closeNav();
    }
});
```

Comment: Well it works but you are lucky (or maybe you knew beforehand) that your window listener executes before the click lestener on the open button or the sidenav would close right after being opened